# how to place a UIViewController in another UIViewController through nib in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nib

I have developed a `DetailViewController`, derived from `UIViewController`. Now I want to use this `DetailViewController` inside another `InfoViewController`'s layout. I found one way to do this by using `addSubView` method. But what I am looking for is to plot it through `nib` file, like other `UIView`s. I want to plot `DetailViewContoller` inside `InfoViewController`'s layout through `nib` file. Is this possible?

Any response will be thankful.

Comment: I think it is not possible in nib file. You have to use code (just my idea)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible..

First remove the referencing outlet for view in DetailViewController.xib.

And in InfoViewController.xib drag-drop Object and edit the custom class to DetailViewController.

Now drag-drop view in InfoViewController.xib and add what ever subviews you want to it. Now add new view referencing outlet to DetailViewController which is under objects.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Satish Thanks for your response. I am surfing around the net and found some statement saying "It is not recommended to put a UIViewController in another UIViewController, instead create custom UIViews and plot it inside UIViewController with dummy UIView and than change the class name to custom view's class name through identity inspector". What do you say on this.